# Moved app from Paid to Free (with IAB) resulted in massive ranking drop

Tags: android, google-play

Yesterday I moved my app which was quite highly ranked from a Paid to a Free app (with in app billing). The app instantly dropped to literal obscurity the second I did it. It was almost as if my ranking value in the database had been reset!

Has anyone experienced this? Will the app recover in the next few days once the rankings get calculated again?

Thanks!